# Automate fixes for issues found by Sonar

Tags: java, automation, sonarqube

I am working on fixing issues caught by sonar on a very old Java project(8 years old approximately ).
It is a huge project with a lot of faulty code that is caught by sonar.
Although they are very trivial fixes but there are a number of them.
Is there a way to automatically fix a series of similar issues ?
Like i have around 1200 cases of "statements should be on separate lines" , to do it manually would take ages.
Can i automate these fixes somehow ?

Comment: Those 1200 cases for example does not sound like a real problem at all. Can't you just make it show errors only? (by the way any formatting tool like "astyle" could format your files. **but** I don't know if this is what it complains about. Edit your Q, include code of such error.)

Comment: I know it is stupid and my first solution also was to remove them from the report , but the management wants it ! I have used the eclipse plugin for java code formatting and solved most of them.Thanks.

Comment: See: http://www.walkmod.com/ and https://github.com/walkmod/

Comment: Today walkmod is a dead project with many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I would want Sonar to change source. It's a code *analyzer*.

You could configure your IDE to format on save and do an initial format of all afflicted source files, so that it puts the satements on separate lines.

Also, you might want to review the importance of the problem and change/edit the Quality Profile.

Comment: I don't want sonar to make changes , I am looking for a separate tool or plugin to do that after I have done code analysis from sonar.
And the statement on separate lines is just an example , that could be solved by using code formatting.
For a better example I have 280 cases of "if/else/for/while/do statements should always use curly braces" , its painful to add 287*2 curly braces manually !! Or around 1000 cases of "Avoid commented-out lines of code" ....is there a way to do this automatically by giving instructions to a plugin ?

Comment: Curlies can also be added by Save Actions or formatting in Eclipse. Comments are a different story, but can be achieved by regex replacement. But again, these are minor issues and could be removed from the profile or be edited.

Answer (score 6):

Currently there are no tools available for automatic fixing of sonarube bugs. There is [walkmod](https://github.com/walkmod/walkmod-sonar-plugin), but it is only for trivial code-smells.

I am currently writing an automatic repair tool for sonarube bugs in java. It uses INRIA's [spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/) to fix the bugs. The github repo is [sonarqube-repair](https://github.com/kth-tcs/sonarqube-repair). It has fixes for five bugs: rule numbers [1854](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-1854), [1948](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-1948), [2055](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2055), [2259](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2259) and [2095](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-2095). I will update this answer once there is some significant progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same resolution to a big number of issues, you can use the [Bulk Change](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Bulk+Changes+on+Issues) feature (introduced in SonarQube 3.7 LTS).

In your particular case, you could also define [issue exclusion rules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) to prevent these issues from being raised on selected parts of the code (introduced in SonarQube 4.0).

Finally, if a particular rule annoys you to the point that it prevents you from working on real issues, you can disable this rule altogether in your quality profile.

Comment: Thanks for the tool.
But i am looking for something that can actually do the code change in bulk for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step (for Eclipse IDE):

1. You can use *Save action* on your whole project: Right-click on your Java project source -> Source -> Format...
2. Right-click on your Java project source -> Source -> Clean Up...
3. Use the *[AutoRefactor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/autorefactor)* plugin: Right-click on your code -> AutoRefactor -> Automatic refactoring
4. Use [WalkMod](http://www.walkmod.com/) (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

You should try https://www.sonarlint.org/, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Viofixer tool -  https://www.viofixer.com/

VioFixer does automatic remediation of the issues reported by sonarqube. VioFixer help reduce the development time and secures completed applications by providing automatic vulnerability remediation options in the coding stage of software development.

Answer (score 0):

Now JavaPerf Consulting launches a service offering tooled to resolve faults identified by SonarQube see more http://www.jperf.com. Soon you will have the product with a command line interface and automatic update.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanthat enables automatic fixing of various issues as reported by Sonar, PMD, CheckStyle and others.

- See https://github.com/solven-eu/cleanthat
- Sonar: https://github.com/solven-eu/cleanthat/blob/master/MUTATORS_BY_TAG.generated.MD#sonar

It is available through `mvn`, `gradle`, and as a GitHub App.